# Spring Hibernate Configuration Issue

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, maven, tomcat

I was getting no JDBC Driver found exception when i started my tomcat server so to resolve this issue i placed mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar in tomcat lib file and after that i am getting below exception : 
nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentException

'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/websystique/springmvc/configuration/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentException

and here is my pom.xml

```
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.websystique.springmvc</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringMVCHibernateManyToManyCRUDExample</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>SpringMVCHibernateWithSpringSecurityExample</name>

    <properties>
        <springframework.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <springsecurity.version>4.0.4.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.11.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>5.1.31</mysql.connector.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jsr303 validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.35</version>
</dependency>
        <!-- SLF4J/Logback -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.1</version>
            </dependency>
        <!-- Servlet+JSP+JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                        <warName>SpringMVCHibernateWithSpringSecurityExample</warName>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <finalName>SpringMVCHibernateWithSpringSecurityExample</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

dom4j is available in build path

[image: dom4j is available in build path]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there might be another version of dom4j in your project dependencies or in the library folder of your tomcat. You can try adding the scope "provided" for dom4j in your pom.xml

```
<groupId>dom4j</groupId>
<artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
<version>1.6.1</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
```

If it works, it means there are another version of dom4j in your tomcat. If it does not work, you should double-check your maven dependency tree again.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the `<dependency>` to `dom4j 1.6.1` it automatically is a dependency of `hibernate-core` so you will have the `dom4j.jar` in the classpath anyway!

MySQL is not a dependency tomcat requires, why did you put it there?! The lib-folder of tomcat is not the correct place for the `mysql.jar` create the `endorsed`-folder please and place it there.

It is better to replace

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

with this properties:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
```

to be able to overload via `mvn -Dmaven.compiler.target=1.8`.

### The problem

As many container-architectures (like tomcats web-container) there are different classloaders for different containers. You placed the `hibernate-core-xx.jar` in the tomcat's `lib`-folder. So the classes are loaded in a lower classloader where no dom4j is available. Yes, your app contains the dom4j and hibernate-core-xx.jar, but as hibernate-core-xx.jar is already loaded by tomcat it is not loaded again and tomcat's classloader can not reach your applications classloader. So, drop all extra jars from tomcat and only have mysql-xxx.jar in endorsed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure dom4j.jar is in the classpath.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hello Shi, the dom4j is present in pom.xml and also available in the build path under maven dependencies.